# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError while running the JUNIT method

Tags: junit

I have been running a simple Junit testclass with a single test method.
I am stuck with the below error.

The stackTrace is as follows

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:263)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl.newMessageFactory(SAAJMetaFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(MessageFactory.java:159)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<init>(SOAPVersion.java:179)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<clinit>(SOAPVersion.java:84)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:241)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.BindingID.<clinit>(BindingID.java:336)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:241)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseBinding(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:425)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:322)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:147)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:267)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:230)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:93)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)
```

Can anyone help me what could be the reason behind it

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Operation [getContextClassLoader] is not supported in jcl-over-slf4j. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#unsupported_operation_in_jcl_over_slf4j (Caused by java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Operation [getContextClassLoader] is not supported in jcl-over-slf4j. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#unsupported_operation_in_jcl_over_slf4j) (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Operation [getContextClassLoader] is not supported in jcl-over-slf4j. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#unsupported_operation_in_jcl_over_slf4j (Caused by java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Operation [getContextClassLoader] is not supported in jcl-over-slf4j. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#unsupported_operation_in_jcl_over_slf4j))
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:532)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:272)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:119)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.components.logger.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:111)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.<clinit>(MessageFactoryImpl.java:103)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:241)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Operation [getContextClassLoader] is not supported in jcl-over-slf4j. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#unsupported_operation_in_jcl_over_slf4j (Caused by java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Operation [getContextClassLoader] is not supported in jcl-over-slf4j. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#unsupported_operation_in_jcl_over_slf4j)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:525)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Operation [getContextClassLoader] is not supported in jcl-over-slf4j. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#unsupported_operation_in_jcl_over_slf4j
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getContextClassLoader(LogFactory.java:366)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.access$000(LogFactoryImpl.java:113)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$1.run(LogFactoryImpl.java:457)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:229)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.loadClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:454)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:406)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: Is that your entire Stacktrace? I would expect to see a "Caused by:" block after this.  You might want to show some code too

Comment: Hi @MrWiggles, I am trying to call a webservice method. and checking whether the response is not null. I am trying to instantiate the webservice by using new, where its throwing this ExceptionInInitializationError.   The statement i am using is as follows  XXXXProxy proxy = new XXXXXProxy();

Comment: But is this your entire Stracktrace? An ExceptionInInitializerException is usually accompanied by a root cause

Comment: The rest of the stacktrace is appended to the main stacktrace

Comment: The Stacktrace is telling you exactly what is wrong.  It even gives you a link to follow to read to resolve it - http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#unsupported_operation_in_jcl_over_slf4j

Comment: Yes @MrWiggles, but i neglected the below StachTrace by just concentrating on the ExceptionInInitializerException Thanks for pointing

Answer (score 2):

I did not have to add any jar files to the CLASSPATH though. I solved it by adding the following system property:

-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory

is this mandatory in running the webservices through JUNit?

Comment: It doesn't run before and I don't know why. Now I set the property as mentioned and it works and I don't know why! +1 even though!